# On using ajax update target id, Login page got rendered inside div tag after time out authentication. MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc

on timeout due to form authentication . my whole login page get render inside div because of ajax updated target id attribute . is there any solution in which my login page open in new window after timeout authenticatoion instead of rendering in div tag.

i can provide my whole code if needed.
help me people.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got another way

In your Logon action you could append a custom response HTTP header:

```
public ActionResult LogOn(){
{
    var model = ...
    Response.AppendHeader("X-LOGON", "Checked");
    return View(model);
}
```

and then subscribe for the complete event and test for the presence of this header and act accordingly:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/some_protected_action',
    success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
        if (XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader('X-LOGON') === 'Checked') {
            // the LogOn page was displayed as a result of this request 
            // probably timeout => act accordingly
             window.location = '<%=Url.Content("~/Account/LogOn") %>';
             window.location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a web app I was working on. You need to set a login controller with its partial view including ONLY the login fields you need. When the app times out, you will be redirected to the login controller which will return the partial view including only the fields you wanted. Also, you can use JQuery or JS to hide all the elements you´re not interested to show while in this page.

Don't forget to set the login controller in the web config for the timeout

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="9000" />
</authentication>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Roisgoen.. its help me..but is there any other way?? like calling javascript before Jquery call or some thing like that...